# Calling RILD layer functions for implement call conferencing in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ril

I want to implement **Call conferencing** in android, for this I am trying to call [RILD](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/telephony.html) functions from my android code, but not able to get the way of how to  call **RILD** functions. I know how to call c and c++ functions from android using NDK, I also got RIL source code from here : [Ril](https://github.com/android/platform_hardware_ril)

For become more specific, I want to implement call conferencing when I am in call with some one and at the same time I got call from a specific number, so I will detect that specific number via applying call receivers and will try to call c and c++ functions of **RILD** via java code for implement call conferencing.

Please tell me the way of implementing **call conferencing** in android by calling RILD.

Answer (score 1):

Call conferencing is a modem feature. There are APIs in the Android framework which are called when conference calling is activated. Call conferencing would work if the relevant APIs are implemented in the RIL. Here are a few APIs for conference calling:

- RIL_REQUEST_CONFERENCE
- RIL_REQUEST_HANGUP_WAITING_OR_BACKGROUND
- RIL_REQUEST_HANGUP_FOREGROUND_RESUME_BACKGROUND

For detailed information, you can visit the following link: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/android-hardware-ril/blob/master/include/telephony/ril.h

Hope this helps :)